# connection String works when declared but not in variable VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection-string, variable-declaration

Connection works but not if I set it with button:

Public Class Form1
    Private Cnstring As String

```
Private connection As New SqlConnection("Server=server; Database=databaseName; User Id=user; Password=password")
```

using the following for variable in the button_click

```
Cnstring = "Server=" & Server.Text & "; Database=" & Database.Text & "; User Id=" & UserID.Text & "; Password=" & Password.Text & ";"

connection.ConnectionString = Cnstring
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
MessageBox.Show(Cnstring)
```

Shows the same connectionstring as the original declaration

Comment: Why not try `Private connection As New SqlConnection(Cnstring)`? Also remove final `;`

Comment: Well - you need to compare the two strings again, because from what you've written here I can already see at least one more semi-colon in the Cnstring that's not in your typed out string - so it's seems likely there are other things different as well.

Comment: You could use an [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx): "Provides a simple way to create and manage the contents of connection strings used by the SqlConnection class."

Comment: Thank you all, I had played around with the string hence the extra semi-colon - removing that and adding cstring to the declaration fixed it. @AndrewMorton will have to look into SqlConnectionStringBuilder as it appears to be the right way forward

Comment: @SyedAbbas SqlConnectionStringBuilder  is convenient as it handles any required quoting or escaping of characters for you, and you don't have to worry about semicolons.